# Almost every convergence imply this equivalence

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, almost-everywhere

> Let $(X,{\cal M},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f_n,f\in L^1(X)$, that is, $\int_X |f_n| {\rm d}\mu < \infty$ and $\int_X |f| {\rm d}\mu < \infty$.
>   Suppose $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere. Then
>   $$ \int_X |f_n| {\rm d}\mu \to \int_X |f| {\rm d}\mu \iff \int_X |f_n-f| {\rm d}\mu \to 0. $$

The $(\Leftarrow)$ implication is trivial, since
$$\left|\int_X |f_n| {\rm d}\mu - \int_X |f|{\rm d}\mu\right| \leq \int_X |f_n-f| {\rm d}\mu.$$

How about the other direction?
I was trying to use some convergence theorem (monotone, dominated, Fatou's lemma), but I don't know how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** (Using @carmichael561's hint)

If we define $g_n=|f_n|+|f|-|f_n-f|$, by triangle inequality we have that $g_n \geq 0$ and it follows from Fatou's lemma that
$$\int \liminf g_n \leq \liminf \int g_n.$$

On one hand, $g_n\to 2|f|$ a.e. since $f_n\to f$ a.e.
On the other hand,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\liminf\int g_n 
 & = \liminf\left(\int |f_n| + \int |f| - \int |f _n-f|\right) \\
 & = \int |f| + \liminf\left(\int |f_n| - \int |f _n-f| \right) \\
 & = \int |f| + \int |f| + \liminf\left(-\int |f_n-f|\right),
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
since $\int |f_n| \to \int |f|$ by hypothesis.

We get then
$$ 0 \leq \liminf\left(-\int |f _n-f| \right),$$
which gives $\limsup\int|f_n-f| \leq 0$.

Now $\int|f_n-f| \geq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ implies $\liminf \int|f_n-f| \geq 0$, and therefore
$$ 0 \leq \liminf \int |f_n-f| \leq \limsup \int |f_n-f| \leq 0,$$
from where the claim follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick with this problem and other similar ones is to find the right sequence of functions to apply Fatou's lemma to. In this case set
$$ g_n=|f_n|+|f|-|f_n-f|.$$

Comment: Thanks for your hint, it was really helpful! I've edited my answer with my new tries. Can you give me some appointment? Thanks in advance

Comment: You were on the right track at the beginning, but you didn't use the fact that $\int|f_n|\to \int |f|$. Once you add this in, you will be able to cancel a factor of $2\int |f|$ from both sides.

Comment: How about now? I got $\limsup(-\int|f_n-f|) = 0$, which is almost what we want!

Comment: It's easier than that: $\liminf_{n}\int g_n=\int|f|+\lim_n\int|f_n|+\liminf_n(-\int |f_n-f|)=2\int|f|-\limsup_{n}\int |f_n-f|$. After cancelling $2\int |f|$ and rearranging, Fatou yields $\limsup_n\int|f_n-f|\leq 0$.

Comment: Why does the first equality hold? It should be "$\geq$", shouldn't? (I'm thinking in $\liminf(a_n+b_n) \geq \liminf a_n + \liminf b_n$).

Comment: See here for the relevant facts about limsup and liminf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Comment: Indeed, if $a_n\to a$ then $\liminf(a_n+b_n) = a + \liminf b_n$. Thank you very much!